# How direct LogCat from DDMS to File

Tags: android, logcat, ddms

My problem is that I try to debug a running app with an exception that happens after long running. In the mean time, the DDMS log cat logs any output from the phone, which is about >1000 messages per second for some buffer output.

Thus, all error messages from my app are not only drowned, but erased from the log output window within moments, with no way to save it in time.

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153910/trying-to-output-my-logcat-to-a-file) was mentioned a way to direct the output into a file, but using

```
adb logcat -s > ~/log2.txt
```

only outputs

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
```

And then nothing. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) are not helpful at all.

Any hints?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175002/write-android-logcat-data-to-a-file

Comment: did you try `logcat -d -s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs, you can find the description of the `-s` option:

```
Sets the default filter spec to silent.
```

So no log will be displayed. You should try to remove this `-s`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the docs, that you've mentioned seems to be helpful. In the table on the referenced page it is said:

> The following table describes the command line options of logcat.
>
> -f <filename>             Writes log message output to . The default is stdout.

Comment: If you'd like to have both stdout and file, look for "tee" command man page

Comment: @Antonio: As mentioned above, that only outputted the two lines and then nothing.